# Stop Crawling urls if class does not exist in table beautifulsoup and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

i'm using a list of urls in a csv file to crawl and extract data from a html table.  i want to stop going through the urls when 'style3' is not present in the table. 
I've created a function that will return false if it's not there, but i'm confused as to how to actually implement it.

Any suggestions for a solution or directions to literature will help greatly as i've not been able to find anything on here to help me figure it out.

i've included 1 url with 'style3' and 1 without.  Thanks for any and all help.

http://www.wvlabor.com/new_searches/contractor_RESULTS.cfm?wvnumber=WV057808&contractor_name=&dba=&city_name=&County=&Submit3=Search+Contractors
http://www.wvlabor.com/new_searches/contractor_RESULTS.cfm?wvnumber=WV057924&contractor_name=&dba=&city_name=&County=&Submit3=Search+Contractors

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

def license_exists(soup):
    contents = []
    with open('WV_urls.csv','r') as csvf:
        urls = csv.reader(csvf)
        for url in urls:
            if soup(class_='style3'):
                return True
            else:
                return False

contents = []
more = True
while more:
    df  = pd.DataFrame(columns=['WV Number', 'Company', 'DBA', 'Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip','County', 'Phone', 'Classification*', 'Expires']) #initialize the data frame with columns
    with open('WV_urls.csv','r') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
        urls = csv.reader(csvf)
        for url in urls:
            contents.append(url) # Add each url to list contents
        for url in contents:  # Parse through each url in the list.
            page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
            df1, header = pd.read_html(page,header=0)#reading with header
            more = license_exists(?????)
            df=df.append(df1) # append to dataframe

            df.to_csv('WV_Licenses_Daily.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Looking at the page/code, it seems like you are searching by a specific `wvnumber`. Is there ever a case where there could be more than one result per page (if that particular `wvnumber` exists)?

Comment: Nope.  There is only 1 record per url.

Comment: When you say you want to stop going through the urls, do you want to break out of the loop (and not look up any urls that would potentially come after that one) or just skip trying to add an empty row to your dataframe and continue on to any subsequent urls?

Comment: while license_exists() == false:

Comment: Break out of the loop. Ultimate goal is to break the loop, email the info I've gathered, then delete the urls I've gone through from the csv

Comment: i'm using a list of pre-built urls in a csv file.

Comment: So after a certain line in the csv (once it has style3/is empty) you want to break and not go through the remainder of the urls?

Comment: this is correct

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the `more` here, you are going through the contents only (your not appending any more to contents). Oh, maybe I see, you want to break if `more is False`?

Comment: Andy - Correct.  It needs to break if more if False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single for-loop and break (there's no need for the `while more`):

```
lst = []
with open('WV_urls.csv','r') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)
    for url in urls:
        page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
        df1, header = pd.read_html(page, header=0)
        if license_exists(BS(page, ‘html.parser’)):
            # if the license is present we don't want to parse any more urls.
            # Note: we don't append this last result (should we?)
            break
        lst.append(df1)

df = pd.concat(lst)
df.to_csv('WV_Licenses_Daily.csv', index=False)
```

*Note: this creates the final DataFrame from a list of the DataFrames, this is more efficient that appending each time.*

Comment: It may be `if not license_exists(...)` I might have misunderstood this function. I might rename it `is_empty` or something.

Comment: with your answer, it kept telling me there wasn't anything to concatenate. i took out the break and lst.append(df1) and replaced with df=df.append(df1) and it worked.   it works like a charm.  i truly appreciate your help.  no sure if i should post what i now have as an answer or should you amend what you have and i accept your answer.  let me know so i can close this out correctly.

Comment: @RobK nothing to concatenate means `lst` is empty, which would be strange. since df is not defined in my code above that sounds wrong. Did you try with `if not license_exists(...)` ?

Comment: right on.  if not license_exists did work.  :)  more than one way to skin a cat?! :) Would you mind if i asked you a couple of other questions about this? Chat maybe?

Comment: For me, it's easier to write a new question (you can add the link here if you like), or just ask the questions here (if they're short). async communication is usually preferable to chat tbh. Glad you got it working!